# Selection Rank Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

Below is an implementation of the selection rank algorithm, which is used to find the elements before the Kth smallest elements in an array. Sometimes this program works well, but it sometimes fails due to stack overflow error (error below code snippet)

```java
public static int rand(int left, int right){
    return left+(int)(Math.random()*(double)(right-left));
}

public static int rank(int[] array, int left, int right, int rank){
    int pivot = rand(left, right);  
    int leftend = partition(array, left, right, array[pivot]);

    int size = leftend - left +1;
    if(size == rank+1){
        for(int i=0; i<=leftend; i++)
        System.out.print(array[i]+" ,");
        return 0;
    }else if(size > rank)
        return rank(array, left, leftend, rank);
    else return rank(array, leftend+1, right, rank - size);

}   

public static int partition(int[] array, int left, int right, int pivot){
    while(true){
        while(left <= right && array[left] <= pivot)
            left++;

        while(right >= left && array[right] > pivot)
        right--;

        if(left > right)
        return left-1;

        int temp = array[left];
        array[left] = array[right];
        array[right] = temp;
    }

 }
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.Random.nextDouble(Random.java:409)
    at java.lang.Math.random(Math.java:712)
    at mod.rand(mod.java:12)
    at mod.rank(mod.java:16)
    at mod.rank(mod.java:25)
```

I think maybe rand() is causing this problem, but I am not sure. Nor do I have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: No, it's likely `rank(` that's the problem.

Comment: probably your recursion never ends

Comment: @Kostia you mean definitely, could you give an example where it fails, that would make it much easier to fix instead of finding our own examples

Comment: I agree with @Kostia. The stack you have in the post indicates that your recursion never ends.

Comment: Oh and @city, not to be a dick but you probably should read: http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: @MaxCharas, why you say the recursion never ends?

Comment: From the http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html

"Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply."

Comment: @MaxCharas,Ok, I get it. But how to fix this problem in my code? I do not know why sometimes it works well, but sometimes not.

Comment: I'm guessing that's what your teacher wants you to understand. :)

Comment: Add a call to `System.out.println("left=" + left + "\tright=" + right + "\tleftend=" + leftend);` right after `int leftend = ...;` so you can see patterns in the recursive calls and maybe identify places where you shouldn't recurse or where you recurse to an overly large sub-range.

Comment: Wouldn't it be significantly easier to just sort the array, then grab all items below an index?

Comment: To add to what @Mike Samuel said: when you have a recursive algorithm that inputs an array and calls itself on subarrays of the array, and you get infinite recursion, usually the problem is either that you have called the routine recursively on the _same_ subarray that was input to the routine, or you're not correctly handling the case where the subarray has length zero.

Comment: @MaxCharas，in fact, this problem and code is from the book Crack the coding interview....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want your `rand` method to return a number between left(inclusive) and right(inclusive). However, the Math.random() method, returns a number between 0.0(inclusive) and 1.0(exclusive). Therefore, in the case when the size fo the subarray being evaluated is 2, (i.e: left=4 and right=5), the `rand` function will only be able to return 4 as a result.
Try changing this line in your `rand` function to ensure it can include the upper bound:

`return left+(int)(Math.random()*(double)(right-left));`

for

`return left+(int)(Math.random()*(double)(right-left + 1));`

Answer (score 1):

The recursion never ends not because the input but because the usage of random,
theoretically random can give you the same number each time.
For example change to:

```
public static int rand(int left, int right)
{
    return right - 1;
}
```

Try it on input :

```
int[] array= {1,2,11,67,35};
rank(array, 0, 4, 2);
```

and you will get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` on this input because the recursion never ends.

Comment: Why 4 and not `left`? 4 is not even guaranteed to be withing [left, right].

Comment: ... for real random numbers, the probability of this happing the thousands of times necessary to cause a stack overflow is (even if only two choices are possible) < 2^-1000. That probability is so close to zero it is far more likely that a cosmic ray flipping a bit in computer memory is responsible for the failure (Yes, `random` is a mere pseudorandom generator, but its distribution is pretty close to uniform. It will *not* keep returning the same number).

Comment: the problem is I did not handle the case that there are only two elements in a subarray, not as you say.

Answer (score 1):

The Javadoc of StackOverflowError says:

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

Since the default limit is quite high, a StackOverflowError usually indicates an infinite recursion.

To effectively diagnose such errors, use a decent IDE with debugging support, set an exception breakpoint for `StackOverflowError`, run your program, and inspect the local variables in the stack once the breakpoint is hit.

Doing that here, we get the following stack:

```
Random.nextDouble() line: 444 [local variables unavailable] 
Math.random() line: 716 
Test.rand(int, int) line: 5 
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 9 
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
Test.rank(int[], int, int, int) line: 18    
...
```

It would appear that rank invokes itself ad infinitum from line 18. Let's verify this by checking the local variables. For the topmost stack frame at line 18:

```
left    97  
right   107 
rank    5   
pivot   102 
leftend 107 
size    11
```

for the one below it:

```
left    97  
right   107 
rank    5   
pivot   101 
leftend 107 
size    11
```

for the one below that

```
left    97  
right   107 
rank    5   
pivot   105 
leftend 107 
size    11
```

Indeed, `left` and `right` are identical in these stack frames, i.e. the algorithm has stopped making progress. We also see that even though a different pivot index is chosen each time, `leftend` remains equal to `right`.

Looking at the array indexes in question, we see:

```
[97]    10  
[98]    10  
[99]    10  
[100]   10  
[101]   10  
[102]   10  
[103]   10  
[104]   10  
[105]   10  
[106]   10  
[107]   10
```

This looks like you are not handling the special case where all elements in the subrange are equal correctly.

Indeed, looking at the code we see that `partition` will always return `right` in such a case, and `rank` will call itself with identical parameters, recursing ad infinitum.

Take home messages:

1. Inspecting the state of the program at the moment of failure (for instance with a debugger and break points) is very useful in finding bugs.
2. Don't ignore corner cases.